# Is it possible to display nested sections in a collapsed fold with vim?

Tags: vim, folding, outline

When a fold is collapsed in vim, all of the nested headings are hidden away so that you can't see what's inside. I'm curious if anyone knows if it's possible or has a solution for `foldtext` function (or through another method) that can display the sections inside a fold when a fold is collapsed.

I'm looking for something that would display folds more like this:

```
+ --   2000 TopSection1                                    " Fold Level 1
+ ---   500 TopSection1 : ChildSection1                    " Fold Level 2
+ ----   50 TopSection1 : ChildSection1 : BottomSection1   " Fold Level 3
+ ---   100 TopSection1 : ChildSection2 : BottomSection1   " Fold Level 2
+ --    500 TopSection2                                    " Fold Level 1
+ ---    25 TopSection2 : ChildSection1                    " Fold Level 2
```

I've been digging around, but have not figured out a method to make this work (or if it's possible). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

the following command gets all folding lines without the body texts in between :

```
:g/{{{/
```

It works for this example below that contains multiple nested folds with foldmethod=marker and default ({{{) mark :

```
Text 1/*{{{*/
some text here
subtext 1.1/*{{{*/
some text here
subsubtext 1.1.1/*{{{*/
some text here/*}}}*/
subsubtext 1.1.2/*{{{*/
some text here/*}}}*//*}}}*/
subtext 1.2/*{{{*/
some text here
subsubtext 1.2.1/*{{{*/
some text here/*}}}*/
subsubtext 1.2.2/*{{{*/
some text here/*}}}*//*}}}*//*}}}*/
Text 2/*{{{*/
some text here
subtext 2.1/*{{{*/
some text here
subsubtext 2.1.1/*{{{*/
some text here/*}}}*/
subsubtext 2.1.2/*{{{*/
some text here/*}}}*//*}}}*/
subtext 2.2/*{{{*/
some text here
subsubtext 2.2.1/*{{{*/
some text here/*}}}*/
subsubtext 2.2.2/*{{{*/
some text here/*}}}*//*}}}*//*}}}*/
```

After you run the :g/{{{/ command, you get this :

```
Text 1/*{{{*/
subtext 1.1/*{{{*/
subsubtext 1.1.1/*{{{*/
subsubtext 1.1.2/*{{{*/
subtext 1.2/*{{{*/
subsubtext 1.2.1/*{{{*/
subsubtext 1.2.2/*{{{*/
Text 2/*{{{*/
subtext 2.1/*{{{*/
subsubtext 2.1.1/*{{{*/
subsubtext 2.1.2/*{{{*/
subtext 2.2/*{{{*/
subsubtext 2.2.1/*{{{*/
subsubtext 2.2.2/*{{{*/
```

If you want to redirect the result to a new buffer, then you can run :

```
:let @a='' | execute 'g/{{{/y A' | new | setlocal bt=nofile | put! a
```

It yanks the {{{ pattern to register "a", opens a new buffer and pastes the reg.
You may then need to expand the result with `zR` if your default is 'collapse folds'.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to play with `foldtext` but also to parse the content of the section to fetch what you want to display.

Answer (score -1):

I use **zr** and **zm** normal commands to open and close another folding level.
I agree that **zr** will also show text between a folding level and a sub-level ; hence it does not fully address your question.
It's seems that a better way would be to use foldmethod=syntax and then filter all folding lines with a **global** (g) command based on the regex of the foldmethod syntax.